# How to do an ODBC connection to OmniTracker?

Tags: excel, odbc

I am set to do some statistics in Excel based on ticket and timeregistration data from OmniTracker (ITSM)

Does anybody know how to do an odbc connection to OmniTracker? I have googled it and found ODBC items - but not related to OmniTracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Omnitracker 10.6 there is a feature called, 'DB Views'.

Your Omnitracker administrator should be able to set up DB Views on your behalf, which should be more convenient for you to query.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct ODBC connection to OmniTracker itself. You can connect to SQL database OT uses. 
Start "OMNITRACKER Service Control Panel" (use Windows search) on your Omnitracker application server to find "ODBC connection string" of your SQL server.
Omnitracker folders can be found in set of DB tables like "[dbo].[UserFields580]".
Every child folder inherits parent fields. So you have to "join" several DB tables [UserFieldsXXX] to get full set of fields.